# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of an image file

Tags: java, image-processing, mean, standard-deviation

I'm new to coding environment, I'm working in an imaging processing project - I have a video file of n size and I'm trying to find a mean and standard deviation of (Height, width and number of frames)that file .  the image file(imgfile_500) is in MAT

here is my code

public class Image_conv {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    String filePath = "C:\\Video_500.h264";
   
    if (!Paths.get(filePath).toFile().exists()){
        System.out.println("File " + filePath + " does not exist!");
        return;
    }

    VideoCapture video500 = new VideoCapture(filePath);


    if (!video500.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Error! video500 can't be opened!");
        return;
    }


    int ntime=20;
    int fps= 60;
    int ds_fac=4;
    int nf = (ntime*fps);

    int wd_ds = 480/ds_fac;
    int hg_ds = 640/ds_fac;
  

    int vsize = wd_ds*hg_ds*nf;


    Mat frame = new Mat(480,640,CvType.CV_64FC3);
    Mat frame500 = new Mat(480,640,CvType.CV_64FC3);
    Mat imgfile_500 = new Mat();

    if (video500.isOpened()) {
    while(true){
        if (video500.read(frame))
        {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame500, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            //System.out.println(frame500.size());

            Imgproc.pyrDown( frame500, frame500, new Size( frame500.cols()/2, frame500.rows()/2 ) );
            Imgproc.pyrDown( frame500, frame500, new Size( frame500.cols()/2, frame500.rows()/2 ) );
          // Imgcodecs.imwrite(i+"led500.jpg", frame500);
          


        // Push a Mat back into MatVector
            imgfile_500.push_back(frame500);
        }else break;
    }
    }

    //System.out.println(imgfile_500.size());

   }
```

}

Comment: what do you consider "mean and standard deviation" **of a video file**? put differently, who is asking this of you, and why don't they explain what they need?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I need to construct an image(new frame) from the video using the mean and standard deviation method. We know the width, height and total number of frames.

Comment: ok so I'm **guessing** that you want those values along the time dimension, i.e. for each pixel through all frames. so you need to load all frames, and then juggle the data (transpose in some way) so that you can conveniently have OpenCV, or whatever else, calculate those values. OpenCV can calculate mean and standard deviation with `cv::meanStdDev`. in python, with numpy, this would be a lot easier, because numpy supports multi-dimensional arrays and operations along arbitrary axes. OpenCV's Mat doesn't really.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, exactly this is what I want. In python, it is a lot easier but unfortunately, I need this in JAVA

Comment: then I'd recommend finding something like numpy, but for java. otherwise you *might* have to touch all the pixels individually (write your own loops). execution speed aside, that's mighty inconvenient. but it's doable.